# Расположенных или расположенной?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно? "*Стоимость зданий и сооружений базы отдыха, расположенных по адресу*" или "*стоимость зданий и сооружений базы отдыха, расположенной по адресу*"?

Answer (score 1):

Чисто грамматически возможно и то, и другое, но  с несколько разным смыслом. Если по данному адресу расположены все здания и сооружения, образующие базу отдыха, то вариант "**расположенной**" может подразумевать стоимость *всей* базы, напр. без стоимости земли; этот же вариант можно истоковать и иначе: назван юридический адрес базы (по расположению офиса), а *все* её здания и сооружения, стоимость которых указывается, находятся в других местах.  Вариант же "**расположенных**" означает стоимость зданий и сооружений базы только по указанному адресу и допускает, что у базы отдыха есть также здания или сооружения (о стоимости которых речь не идёт), расположенные в других местах.